# Error translating with i18next in react modal child component using "withTranslation" HOC

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I'm using react.i18next framework (https://react.i18next.com/). I'm quite new with React but the internationalization is working using withTranslation HOC (https://react.i18next.com/latest/withtranslation-hoc).

The problem is in one specific child component inside Modal.

These are the involved lines in my index.jsx file:

```
...
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from './i18n';

const Loader = () => (
  <div>loading texts...</div>
);

const Index = () => (
    <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App/>
          </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
      </I18nextProvider>
    </Suspense>
)
```

And these in my login.jsx (login modal). **Translations here are working**:

```
...
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

class LoginModal extends Component {
  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;

    const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    };
    return (
      <Modal isOpen={this.props.show} toggle={this.props.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggle}>Login</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <p>{t('title')}</p>
          {this.state.isLogin ? (<LoginForm />) : (<RegisterForm />)}
        </ModalBody>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default withTranslation("landing")(LoginModal);
```

But when I tried to translate content inside the child component (LoginForm) in the same way:

```
...
import { withTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { t, i18n } = this.props;
    const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    };
    return (
      <p>FORM</p>
    )
  }
}

export default withTranslation("form")(LoginForm)
```

I get the following error:

`useTranslation.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'i18n' of undefined at useTranslation (useTranslation.js:12)`

At the beginning I suposed the problem was related with context, because the modal is outside of the App component that contains the  wrapper but I tried inside the modal as you can see in the previous example and here translations are working.

I tried to pass the i18n prop from the modal to the LoginForm child component, but internationalization framework is not reading the local i18n but the i18n property from the context, I think. These are the lines related with the error inside the framework code:

`var _ref = getHasUsedI18nextProvider() ? useContext(I18nContext) : {},
      i18nFromContext = _ref.i18n;`

I did a lot of reseach and I get some similar errors but nothing that can solve my problem. Not very much information using the HOC for translations and this is the only way that worked for me using i18next.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Edu